# accordion on mobile, tabs on desktop in Magento2

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2

in this file from Magento2

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details $block */
/** @var \VENDOR\ThemeBase\Helper\Catalog\ProductView $_vendorHelper */
/** @var Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper */

$_vendorHelper = $this->helper(VENDOR\ThemeBase\Helper\Catalog\ProductView::class);
$_style = $_vendorHelper->getCollateralDataStyle();
$_firstOpened = $_vendorHelper->getCollateralDataOpened();
if ($_firstOpened === false) {
    $_firstOpened = "0";
}
$_multiCollapsible = $_vendorHelper->getCollateralDataMultiCollapsible();
if ($_style == 'tab') {
    $_mageInit = '{"tabs":{"openedState":"active", "active": ' . $_firstOpened . ' }}';
} elseif ($_style == 'accordion') {
    $_mageInit = '{"accordion":{"openedState":"active", "active": ' . $_firstOpened . ', "multipleCollapsible":' . $_multiCollapsible . ', "collapsible": true}}';
}
?>

<div class="product-info-container row">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) : ?>
        <div class="product info detailed <?php echo $_vendorHelper->getProductViewColBtm1Classes() ?>">
            <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
            <div class="product data items"
                 data-mage-init='{"mage/tabs": {"openedState": "active", "animate": {"duration": 200}, "active": 0, "disabledState": "disabled"}}'>
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) : ?>
                    <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                    ?>
                    <div class="data item title" data-role="collapsible">
                        <a class="data switch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="trigger" href="#<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>"
                           id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="data item content"
                         id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>"
                         data-role="content">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="data item title" data-role="collapsible">
                    <a class="data switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-reviews" tabindex="-1">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $escaper->escapeHtml(__("Reviews")) ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                        <div class="data item content"
                             id="tab-reviews"
                             data-role="content" class="feedaty_widget" data-snippets="4" data-type="product_tab" data-variant="Recensioni-Verticale-Alternative"
                             data-id="selettore4"
                             data-gui="all" data-lang="all" data-sku="prod1" data-snippets="1"
                             data-location="sede1"></div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="product info secondary <?php echo $_vendorHelper->getProductViewColBtm2Classes() ?>">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('contenitore.review'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'collapsible',
        'matchMedia',
        'domReady!',
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        var helpers = {
            domReady: function() {
                var updateCollapsibleType = function($accordions) {
                    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
                        // Desktop: Switch to Tabs
                        $accordions.collapsible('deactivate');
                        $accordions.collapsible('option', 'collapsible', false);
                    } else {
                        // Mobile: Switch to Accordion
                        $accordions.collapsible('activate');
                        $accordions.collapsible('option', 'collapsible', true);
                    }
                };

                var $container = $('.accordion'),
                    $accordions = $container.find('.data'),
                    accordionOptions = {
                        collapsible: true,
                        header: '.heading',
                        trigger: '',
                        content: '.content',
                        openedState: 'active',
                        animate: false
                    };

                $accordions.each(function(index, elem){
                    var $this = $(elem),
                        $accordion = $this.collapsible(accordionOptions);

                    $accordions.push($accordion);
                });

                // Update the collapsible type on window resize
                $(window).on('resize', function () {
                    updateCollapsibleType($accordions);
                });

                // Initial setup
                updateCollapsibleType($accordions);
            }
        };

        helpers.domReady();
    });
</script>
```

I need this behaviour:

**Mobile**

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/jquery-widgets/accordion/
[image]

**Desktop**

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/jquery-widgets/tabs/

[image]

I'm using Jquery, all I need is accordion on mobile, and tabs on desktop. the reviews tab is added externally.

Comment: Dynamically "switching" between the two display forms, based on just one set of HTML elements, is rather hard to do - especially, when the two require a significantly different structure. Much easier, to create the proper HTML structure for both upfront - and then show one of these sections on desktop and hide it on mobile, and vice-versa for the other one.